# How does std::forward work in the context of a fold expression?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, rvalue, stdmove

In the MSVC STL, the [implementation of `std::apply`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/ca641a0eac3d03e7503cbb35b63d758d20378f72/stl/inc/tuple#L1070-L1078) is as follows:

```cpp
template <class _Callable, _Tuple_like _Tuple, size_t... _Indices>
constexpr decltype(auto) _Apply_impl(_Callable&& _Obj, _Tuple&& _Tpl, index_sequence<_Indices...>) noexcept(/* [...] */) {
    return _STD invoke(_STD forward<_Callable>(_Obj), _STD get<_Indices>(_STD forward<_Tuple>(_Tpl))...);
}
```

In the expression `_STD get<_Indices>(_STD forward<_Tuple>(_Tpl))...`, `std::get` is called the same number of times as the length of the tuple. However, with each invocation of `std::get`, there is a corresponding invocation of `std::forward.` When forwarding an rvalue, `std::forward` is equivalent to `std::move`, implying multiple calls to `std::move` for the `_Tpl` object. This seems to be potentially invalid. Could someone help explain my concern?

I've tried searching through various resources, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. Starting from the definition also hasn't convinced me.

Comment: Please note that there are *many* implementations of the C++ standard library. There's no single "the" standard library.

Comment: As for [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), it doesn't really do anything, all it does is converting the argument to an rvalue reference. Why would it be problematic with many move calls? Why would it be invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> implying multiple calls to std::move for the _Tpl object. This seems to be potentially invalid.

Yes, there are multiple calls to `std::move` on the tuple. But this in itself is not invalid.

Generally, passing an object with `std::move` to a function is a promise to that function that the caller won't rely on the state of the object after the call. Therefore a second `std::move` to another function would generally have incorrect semantics, because it would pass an unspecified state to the second function.

But there are several cases where a function makes stronger promises to the caller. For example `std::unique_ptr` promises that after calling its move constructor or move assignment the passed object will be in an empty state. So it can still be used as a null pointer after the `std::move`.

For `std::get` is known even more precisely what it will do: It will do nothing except return a reference to the requested element of the tuple. And depending on whether the tuple was passed as rvalue or lvalue it will also return lvalue or rvalue references as appropriate when combined with the element's type.

So, `std::get` won't actually modify the state of the tuple and the pack expansion (which is not a fold expression btw.) will result in a list of one reference to each element of tuple, potentially as lvalue or rvalue, but never two rvalues to the same object. Thus, when passing the references on to the invoked function, there is no problem equivalent to generic double-`std::move`s.

Comment: One might naively try to `forward` elements rather than the tuple itself; but that would almost always move the elements and create UB for most cases. By forwarding the top level object(tuple in this case), code allows the compiler to choose correct behavior for elements.

Comment: @user17732522 `std::forward_like` has a different intended use case. I remember it from the **deduced this** approved C++20 feature proposal. `forward_like` seems to have emerged as a follow up proposal. For `apply`-`tuple` case, imagine what happens for reference capturing tuples(`std::tie`, `std:: forward_as_tuple`); top-level forward keeps the template sane, while element-wise forwarding(`forward_like`) changes valueness and results in ill-formed program.

Comment: @Red.Wave Ehm yes, I somehow wasn't thinking straight there.

Comment: @user17732522 No! You were. I just happened to have once tried to implement tuple. It leads to emotional damage;)