# How to move std::tuple elements out of a class object?

Tags: c++, c++14, undefined-behavior, move-semantics, stdtuple

## Problem:

I would like to move the elements out of a class member tuple-type variable, but I wonder whether the following code (near-minimal example, being limited to C++14) is allowed:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

// For testing, assume a move-only class template:
enum class Index { idx1, idx2, idx3 };
template <Index I>
struct B {
    ~B()                    = default;
    B(B&&)                  = default;
    B& operator= (B&&)      = default;
    B(B const&)             = delete;
    B& operator= (B const&) = delete;
    
    Index getIndex() { return I; }
};

// Class to consider
template <Index... Is_>
class A
{
    public:
        A(B<Is_>&&... _b) : m_tuple{std::move(_b)...} {}
        
        template <Index... Js_>
        std::tuple<B<Js_>...> moveBs() &&
        {
            return { std::move(*this).template moveB<Js_>()... };
        }

    private:
        template <Index J_>
        B<J_> moveB() &&
        {
            // Attention: The entire tuple shall be moved, not the return
            //            value(s) of std::get<>() - see answer to question
            //            77664807: "How does std::forward work in the
            //            context of a fold expression?",  thanks to
            //            'user12002570' for pointing this out.
            return std::get<B<J_>>(std::move(m_tuple));
        }
        std::tuple<B<Is_>...>   m_tuple;
};

// Output only as an example, to try out
void print(Index _i)
{ 
    std::cout << ( (_i == Index::idx1) ? "Index::idx1" 
                 : (_i == Index::idx2) ? "Index::idx2"
                 : (_i == Index::idx3) ? "Index::idx3" 
                 : "unknown!")
              << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A<Index::idx1,
      Index::idx2,
      Index::idx3> a{   B<Index::idx1>{}, 
                        B<Index::idx2>{}, 
                        B<Index::idx3>{}  };
    B<Index::idx1> b1{};
    B<Index::idx2> b2{};

    // Call to consider
    std::tie(b1, b2) = std::move(a).moveBs<Index::idx1,
                                           Index::idx2>();
    
    // Usage of objects b1,b2 - verify the result of the previous call
    print(b1.getIndex());
    print(b2.getIndex());
}
```

The question referred to in the example code is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664877/3052687)

Clang and GCC compilers accept this code, but moving several times from object `a`, as it is done through `moveBs<Js_>()`, feels illegal.

Compiler options used: `--std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wpedantic -Werror`.

## Questions:

1. Is it allowed to move from a member like `m_tuple` if that is done from a `&&`-qualified method like `moveB<>()`?
2. Is it allowed to "invoke" `std::move(*this)` multiple times, as it seems to be done in the parameter pack expansion in `moveBs<>()`?

Comment: [How does std::forward work in the context of a fold expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77664807/how-does-stdforward-work-in-the-context-of-a-fold-expression)

Comment: @user12002570 - Thanks for bringing this link here! I think that discussion is very related to my question. I'll update my example code to highlight where the other SO thread must be taken into account.

Comment: @HelpingHand I noticed that you updated the post but it doesn't change anything. The answers to your two questions are still the same.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - do you consider this question a duplicate of the other one? Should I withdraw it again?

Comment: @HelpingHand I wouldn't concider that other Q&A a duplicate and noone has voted to close it as dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it allowed to move from a member like `m_tuple` if that is done from a `&&`-qualified method like `moveB<>()`?

Yes.

> Is it allowed to "invoke" `std::move(*this)` multiple times, as it seems to be done in the parameter pack expansion in `moveBs<>()`?

Yes.

What you do not want to do is to move multiple times from a resource that may end up in a valid but indeterminate state. Your code doesn't do that.